# MS Excel: MIN and FIND/SEARCH

Tags: microsoft-excel, string-manipulation

I am trying to figure out what exactly excel is doing with these two functions.

I have many rows of strings in a single column. I want to pull out the first numeric in those strings. The first number can be 0,1,2,3...,9 and the total length of the string varies. I want to find the first number and return it and everything after it. I found the following code on google while searching for how to find the first numeric in a string but I don't understand how it works. The only changes I've made is that I added a failure action to the IF-statement.

```
=MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1))=TRUE,FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1),"N/A"))
```

As I read this, it says the following: Are any numbers in the array `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}` found in my string? If there are then `ISNUMBER() = TRUE` will pass and the code will execute the second `FIND()` function. It then passes the results of the second `FIND()` function (i.e. the positions of all the numerics in the string) to the `MIN()` function which takes the minimum (i.e. the first position).

This *does* work correctly but what I don't understand is if I do it without the IF-statement, then it gives me a `#VALUE` error. In other words, if I do this

```
=MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1))
```

I get `#VALUE` in the output cell. Why? I just took out the IF-statement as far as I can see.

Can anyone explain what I am missing here. Is it the way excel passes information from the `IF()` function?

Answer (score 0):

`Min` is giving you the minimum of numbers in your string `A1`, so if `A1` contains letters and numbers (for example `123text0`) `Find` without `If` and `isnumeric()` will put `#value` in the place of characters and number in the place of digits.

`MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1))=TRUE,FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1),"N/A"))` is putting `N/A` instead of `#value` and `Min` will ignore the text `N/A` but cannot ignore the error `#value`.

`If()` is testing the `Find()` for being numbers so if `isnumeric` is `true` it writes the digits, if not it will write `N/A Min(1,2,3,"N/A","N/A"..)=1`, but when you remove `If` the `Min(1,2,3,#value,#value..)=#value`.